# How can I increment repeated values in Google Sheets?

Tags: regex, date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a sales forecast spreadsheet, which I'm looking to generate cash flow data off of.

My sales forecast looks like so

```
Base Revenue | Contract Date | Years Subscribed

€45,000      | 30/06/2020    |  3
```

Is there a way to return the future payment dates based on the contract date and years subscribed. Payments would occur on the contract date and every year thereafter for the duration of the contract.

Taking the example, we would want to see

```
Payment Date

30/06/2020

30/06/2021

30/06/2022
```

I have been able to get repeated values into an array using the following formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",", ARRAYFORMULA(REPT(B2:B100 & ",",$C2:$C100))), ","))
```

In this case, it repeats the original contract date. I need to further increment that date.

The preference would be to have a single formula, rather than repeating per row since I cannot control what users will input into this.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(B2), "(.*/)")&
 ROW(INDIRECT("B"&YEAR(B2)&":B"&YEAR(B2)+C2-1)))
```

[image: 0]